# React hook forms to watch fields on dynamic forms

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I'm implementing a dynamic form using the react hook forms solution. The form is to create quotations so the users can add as many rows as they want, and in each row the have to inform:

- Product
- Material
- Units

Once these 3 fields are completed our api will return the price for that row.

Now I've managed to read the form value when submiting using the handleSubmit hook but now I'm trying to implement the watch function so each time one of the three inputs on each rows is filled it checks for the other two and if they are filled too reach the api to get the line price.

Besides that, I want to use the same functionality to check if user updates the product, units or material so I should recalculate the line price.

On the first render the user has no lines and when he clicks on a button I fill an array with `{}` and update the view to add a new line.

This is the code I'm working with:

```
const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);
  const [year, setYear] = useState();
  const [generation, setGeneration] = useState();

  const newRowHandler = () => {
    setRows((prevState) => [...prevState, {}]);
  };
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    watch,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data.row);
    success();
  };

  const generations = [
    { value: 1, brand: "BMW", name: "BMW Serie 3 E70 3p" },
    { value: 2, brand: "BMW", name: "BMW Serie 3 E70 5p" },
    { value: 2, brand: "BMW", name: "BMW Serie 5 E72 5p" },
  ];

  const yearHandler = (event) => {
    setYear(event.target.value);
  };

  const generationHandler = (event) => setGeneration(event.target.value);

  console.log(watch()); // console.log del estado total del formulario cada vez que escribimos algo

  const watcher = (control, name) => {
    const value = watch(name);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className={classes.new__select_generation}>
        <div className={classes.new__select__generation_year}>
          <label>Año</label>
          <select name="year" onChange={yearHandler}>
            <option value="">--Selecciona un año--</option>
            <option value="2000">2000</option>
            <option value="2001">2001</option>
            <option value="2002">2002</option>
            <option value="2003">2003</option>
            <option value="2004">2004</option>
            <option value="2005">2005</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div className={classes.new__select__generation__name}>
          <label>Año</label>
          <select
            name="year"
            onChange={generationHandler}
            disabled={year ? false : true}>
            <option value="">--Selecciona una generación--</option>
            <option value="1">BMW Serie 3 E70 3p</option>
            <option value="2">BMW Serie 3 E70 5p</option>
            <option value="3">BMW Serie 5 E72 5p</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className={classes.new__buttons}>
        <button
          className={classes.new__buttons__add_row}
          onClick={newRowHandler}
          disabled={generation ? false : true}>
          Nueva fila
        </button>
      </div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        {rows?.length > 0 &&
          rows?.map((row, index) => {
            return (
              <div className={classes.new} key={index}>
                <div className={classes.new__row}>
                  <div className={classes.new__row__field}>
                    <label>Producto</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      {...register(`row.${index}.product`)}
                      onChange={watcher(`row.${index}.product`)}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className={classes.new__row__field}>
                    <label>Material</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      {...register(`row.${index}.material`)}
                      onChange={watcher(`row.${index}.material`)}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className={classes.new__row__field}>
                    <label>Unidades</label>
                    <input
                      type="number"
                      {...register(`row.${index}.units`)}
                      min="1"
                      onChange={watcher(`row.${index}.units`)}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className={classes.new__row__field}>
                    <label>Precio</label>
                    <input
                      type="number"
                      {...register(`row.${index}.price`)}
                      disabled
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className={classes.new__separator}></div>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        <div className={classes.new__buttons}>
          {/* Quiza debería de ser un link */}
          <Link to="/quotes" style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "black" }}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleLeft} /> Volver al listado
          </Link>
          <button type="submit" disabled={rows.length > 0 ? false : true}>
            Guardar
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};
```

I've tried using the `onChange` on each input and calling a function that receives the input to the `watch` function but it's not working this is the function I tried:

```
const linePriceHandler = (index) => {
    console.log(`line price handler`);
    console.log(`${watch(`${index}.product`)}`);
    console.log(`${watch(`${index}.material`)}`);
    console.log(`${watch(`${index}.units`)}`);
  };
```

The idea is that every time one of the field gets updated I can have access to all the fields on the same line. Maybe the `watch` function is not the appropriate function?

[Link to the sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-currying-zh6fo?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Can you provide a codesandbox please ?

Comment: @Joris I just added the link to the question

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `getValues()` on input's change. So you will be able to get all form values and work with it.

https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/getvalues